# Tensorflow LSTM not learning despite large network, small sample size and preprocessed data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have the following Neural Network:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(150, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))  # Activation_layer

opt = Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-6)

model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The network will be fed sequential data, and is trying to classify the data to either 1 or 0.

Example of one of the samples:

X:

```
[[0.56450562 0.69825955 0.57768099 0.69077864]
 [0.58818427 0.70355375 0.61725885 0.30270281]
 [0.57407927 0.72501532 0.59603936 0.29196058]
 [0.56501804 0.69072662 0.59064673 0.66034622]
 [0.56552001 0.70354009 0.59136487 0.1586415 ]
 [0.56501496 0.68205159 0.57877241 0.62252169]
 [0.54535762 0.67067675 0.58414928 0.9077868 ]
 [0.56197241 0.71226839 0.5920788  0.1339519 ]
 [0.57308813 0.70469134 0.59749238 0.27085101]
 [0.56146488 0.69258436 0.58377929 0.7065891 ]
 [0.55943607 0.69106406 0.59569036 0.69378783]
 [0.5670203  0.68271571 0.58702014 0.70585781]
 [0.58320254 0.71228948 0.60867704 0.19280208]
 [0.56904526 0.71490986 0.59027546 0.35757948]
 [0.56398908 0.67858148 0.58197139 0.75064535]
 [0.57005691 0.7062191  0.60363236 0.38345417]
 [0.5705625  0.70394121 0.58630169 0.19171352]
 [0.56145905 0.69106039 0.58340288 0.76821359]
 [0.55183665 0.68991404 0.5935228  0.53419864]
 [0.56549613 0.68800419 0.58013082 0.74470123]
 [0.54926442 0.67315638 0.58336904 0.77819332]
 [0.56802882 0.71842805 0.60222782 0.12845991]
 [0.59591035 0.70927878 0.61161172 0.68023463]
 [0.56904526 0.713053   0.58773435 0.20017562]
 [0.58321778 0.69939555 0.61194041 0.47063807]
 [0.57814777 0.71113559 0.58991151 0.62149082]
 [0.56044844 0.69257776 0.58738045 0.39285414]
 [0.56853912 0.70091102 0.59713724 0.21938703]
 [0.56398364 0.69939514 0.59316136 0.43031303]
 [0.56701957 0.69901619 0.5935228  0.39333831]
 [0.56701916 0.68082684 0.58701647 0.84346823]
 [0.57765044 0.70812209 0.60147335 0.38961049]
 [0.58975543 0.71340576 0.6050683  0.61008348]
 [0.57207508 0.70280098 0.59821004 0.44573693]
 [0.56702537 0.71035313 0.59424384 0.30333905]
 [0.58417429 0.69901619 0.60288387 0.7210835 ]
 [0.56400225 0.70128289 0.59028243 0.42721302]
 [0.5725759  0.70241467 0.60000056 0.22784863]
 [0.57055816 0.69561772 0.59136355 0.66855609]
 [0.58766922 0.70995564 0.60538235 0.71163122]
 [0.57206444 0.69788453 0.59567842 0.707679  ]
 [0.5775922  0.70956495 0.60249313 0.32745877]
 [0.57407031 0.6997696  0.57952909 0.54327415]
 [0.55346759 0.69223554 0.58920848 0.27867972]
 [0.58612784 0.7031614  0.617901   0.76338596]
 [0.58659902 0.72005896 0.60604811 0.48696192]
 [0.57004823 0.70539865 0.59173347 0.47288217]
 [0.57405756 0.7023936  0.59030119 0.49981083]
 [0.55801818 0.68813345 0.58564415 0.38486918]
 [0.55900944 0.69300306 0.58527681 0.41875207]
 [0.56351994 0.68585174 0.58239563 0.70965566]
 [0.5509523  0.69524821 0.59280378 0.46280846]
 [0.56753474 0.69713124 0.59172507 0.29915786]
 [0.56753451 0.69939326 0.5978358  0.59996518]
 [0.56954889 0.69109776 0.57734904 0.27905973]
 [0.55595081 0.68429475 0.59424321 0.86881108]
 [0.57005376 0.71486763 0.60215717 0.20096972]
 [0.57509255 0.70467308 0.59028491 0.29196681]
 [0.5584625  0.68958804 0.59028342 0.24039387]
 [0.57005412 0.70203582 0.5964024  0.59344888]]
```

y:

```
1
```

The issue I am having, is that the loss starts out at around 0.69 and never decreases significantly (it fluctuates a bit), and the loss and validtation loss both stay around 0.5

What I've tried so far:

- Checked Training and validation data for NaN's or values < 0 or > 1 -> Not found
- Reduced sample size dramatically (down to 50 samples) and a network that should be more than large enough to overfit, but alas still the same result.
- Preprocessed the data in a completely different way
- Using sigmoid activation instead of softmax to classify the labels.
- Reduced learning rate
- Removing the second last dense layer
- Used LeakyReLU with alpha=0.05

Although the data could be next to random, shouldn't a sufficiently large network easily overfit onto 50 samples or less?

Answer (score 2):

2 suggestions:

- It appears you have a binary classification problem (either 0 or 1), perhaps you could try a binary cross entropy loss instead?
- Are you using a method such as to_categorical to one-hot encode your labels?

Other factors that can sometimes dramatically affect accuracies that you haven't mentioned trying/changing:

- Using different optimizers
- Exploring different architectures: have you considered maybe a CNN-LSTM model? Or have you tested on different architectures, do some learn better than others?

Comment: Binary cross entropy would be helpful and don't forget to check precision and recall. Sometimes we get 0 for them.

Comment: Unfortunately, the graphics card on my computer fried so I haven't been able to test all suggestions, but binary cross entropy yielded roughly the same loss and no decrease.

Comment: How large is your training/test/validation set and have you applied any data augmentation techniques?